# error on packaging project in visual studio with mono android

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio-2012, mono

I create my first android application in visual studio with mono android.when the run project show this message: 1.Could not create the Android package. See the Output (Build) window for more details.
[APIs in sdk manager picture](http://barnamenevis.org/attachment.php?attachmentid=134693&d=1440825221)

[application properties picture](http://barnamenevis.org/attachment.php?attachmentid=134694&d=1440825921)

### please help.

**out put log:

### C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1414,2): error MSB6004: The specified task executable location "E:\Users\hossein\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\zipalign.exe" is invalid. [C:\Users\hossein\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\AndroidApplication1\AndroidApplication1\AndroidApplication1.csproj]**

"C:\Users\hossein\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\AndroidApplication1\AndroidApplication1\AndroidApplication1.csproj" (SignAndroidPackage target) (1) ->
(_Sign target) -> 
  C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1402,2): warning : No -tsa or -tsacert is provided and this jar is not timestamped. Without a timestamp, users may not be able to validate this jar after the signer certificate's expiration date (2044-11-23) or after any future revocation date. [C:\Users\hossein\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\AndroidApplication1\AndroidApplication1\AndroidApplication1.csproj]
  C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1402,2): warning : Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xms256m -Xmx512m [C:\Users\hossein\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\AndroidApplication1\AndroidApplication1\AndroidApplication1.csproj]

"C:\Users\hossein\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\AndroidApplication1\AndroidApplication1\AndroidApplication1.csproj" (SignAndroidPackage target) (1) ->
(_Sign target) -> 
  C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1414,2): error MSB6004: The specified task executable location "E:\Users\hossein\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\zipalign.exe" is invalid. [C:\Users\hossein\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\AndroidApplication1\AndroidApplication1\AndroidApplication1.csproj]

Comment: post the build output log

Comment: please read the log out put

Answer (score 0):

Ok, that's a heap problem, in the Android Build tab increase the heap size to 1G, then it will compile.

Comment: As i Said, on the properties of the project go to the Android Build section and chage the "Java heap" option to 1G

Comment: ok there is another error, you're missing zipalign.exe, is that file in E:\Users\hossein\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\?

Comment: is that file in E:\Users\hossein\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\?

Comment: Then your Android SDK is misconfigured or not installed at all, reinstall it and configure it's path on the SDK location options.